# .htaccess wont rewrite as needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess isnt rewriting clean URL's like I want it to. Instead of doing what it's instructed to do, it gives me a 404 error!

I want this:

```
http://localhost/somepossiblepath
```

to be routed to this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?route=somepossiblepath
```

Currently, this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have a current script testing to see if it will work or not:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['route'] ?>
```

It will work when I type in `/index` but not when I type in anything else.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In an .htaccess file, the string that is matched against by rule regexps has the base directory stripped off (`/` in the case of a `DOCROOT/.htaccess`).  So `^/(.*)$` won't match.  What you need, for example is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: you need to do more than just give a bald answer.  @nonplus probably won't even notice you've dropped the leading  `/`.  I've edited your answer to show what I mean.